# error: A value of type 'RxList<Proje>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Proje>'

Tags: flutter, dart

Using the Get package as state management, I wrote a controller that was working yesterday. Now it's crying.
Here is the definition:

```
class ProjeController extends GetxController {
  RxList<Proje> projeList = <Proje>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    List storedProjes = GetStorage().read<List>('projelist');
    if (storedProjes != null) {
      projeList = storedProjes.map((e) => Proje.fromJson(e)).toList().obs;
    }
```

And when I try to get the list assigned to a variable here:

```
final ProjeController pc = Get.find();
List<Proje> pl = pc.projeList;
```

I get this error:
error: A value of type 'RxList' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'. (invalid_assignment at [esrefmasraf] lib\screens\projeeklesil.dart:16)

I tried `List<Proje>.empty(growable:true).obs`, gave the same error along with breaking other parts of the code.

I'm pretty sure it was working yesterday, but history shows no changes in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update:

```
List<Proje> pl = pc.projeList.toList();
```

Comment: did that before as well, returns error: 'A value of type 'List<Proje> (where Proje is defined in \esrefmasraf\lib\models\proje.dart)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Proje> (where Proje is defined in \esrefmasraf\lib\models\proje.dart)'. (invalid_assignment at [esrefmasraf] lib\screens\projeeklesil.dart:16)'

Comment: Could you please check if you are using relative imports? (should be using 'package:...' imports)

Comment: Great! I was just doing  that. Thanks. Those awesome imports costed just a couple of hours, it's not that bad :(

Comment: Yup, it's a sneaky bug in Dart